# Function having increasing and decreasing intervals

Tags: functions

What does it mean when the intervals of a function are increasing or decreasing?
For example,w hat does it mean when it says a function is decreasing on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$ or for example or increasing on the interval $(0,-\infty)$?

Comment: We don't say that the intervals of a function are increasing/decreasing. We say that a function is increasing/decreasing over an interval. And it means that as you move to the right on the interval, the value of the function increases or decreases. So, if you think of a function just like an airplane that is moving in a time interval, if the airplane is increasing its latitude, it's like the function is increasing and when the airplane is decreasing its altitude, its like the function is decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f$ is increasing on an interval $I$ if whenever $x$ and $y$ are points in the interval, if $x$ is larger than $y$, then $f(x)$ is larger than $f(y)$.  In other words, $f$ is increasing on an interval $I$ if for all $x, y \in I$ with $x > y$, then $f(x) > f(y)$.

Likewise, a function $f$ is decreasing on an interval $I$ if for all $x, y \in I$ with $x > y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) for more info.

Comment: Note that this defines what is often called *strictly* increasing. Many take "increasing" to mean *weakly* increasing.